# Generate a specific wordlist using Crunch

Tags: passwords

I would like to create a wordlist.

My password contains a word (rather a name the first letter is small or big all the others are small) and if numbers are inside, then at the end and in the order 1 or 12 or 123 or 12345 maybe an exclamation mark is last.

So:

1. The password begins with a small or a large letter, the remaining letters are small. Most likely it is a name.
2. If numbers should occur in the password, then at the end and if in the order of 1 or 12 or 123 or 1234 or 12345
   Maybe one is! at the end.

Comment: This is more of a programming question than a security question. I'm also not sure why you want to force a particular tool to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know that well. Are there scripts as a template?

I have to rausfonden the password of my ZIP file which I have forgotten.

Comment: This is a also a common usage FAQ for password-cracking tools. Since it's actually built into most of them, I consider it to be on topic.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you shouldn't need to.

What you're describing - combining a wordlist with a bruteforce-generated suffix - is built into most major password-cracking suites.

When dealing with fast hashes on GPU, it is implemented in a way that results in much faster cracking speeds for fast hashes because the candidates are generated on internally (on the GPU itself) instead of externally (on the CPU and then fed over the bus to the GPU).

In hashcat, it's called *hybrid* mode (`-m 6` and `-m 7`, wordlist+mask and mask+wordlist respectively). In John the Ripper, you can use `?w` in your masks with `--wordlist`.

If you're using a tool that doesn't have native support for hybrid attacks, A) you'll still need to do this but B) you'll probably get general better results if you switch to a suite that does.